# Base64 Decode Pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, apache-kafka, base64, debezium

I am trying to base64 decode a value (16-bit signed big endian) from a Kafka <> Debezium Payload using a User Defined Function in Snowflake. Unfortunately, I am only able to use Javascript and Snowflake uses Javascript Standard Library. I found a working example for NodeJS which uses the Buffer module but that is not usable in Javascript.

```
 var kafkaDecodeNumber = function(base64EncodedNumber) {
     var byteArray = Buffer.from(base64EncodedNumber, 'base64');
     var value = 0;
     for (var i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
         value = (value * 256) + byteArray[i];
     }
     return value;
 };

var float = parseFloat(kafkaDecodeNumber( price )).toFixed(38) / 100
```

Here are some working code examples I am using elsewhere

Python

```
    ctx = decimal.Context()
    ctx.prec = 38
    result = ctx.create_decimal(
        int.from_bytes(base64.b64decode(byte_value), byteorder='big')
        ) / 100
    return result
```

Ruby

`event.get('price').unpack1('m*').unpack1('B*').to_i(2) / 100.0)`

Any assistance here would be great!

Comment: can you provide an example of encoded string and expected decoded result?

Comment: Sure! 
Decode strong: "D6A="
Expected result as number: 40

Comment: `new DataView(new Uint8Array(atob(base64EncodedNumber).split('').map(v => v.charCodeAt(0))).buffer).getInt16(0);`

Comment: @Bravo the output of that is correct, however, I get this following error when executing in Snowflake:

Comment: @Bravo sorry mate, comment out cut off. See below

```[P0000][100132] JavaScript execution error: Uncaught ReferenceError: atob is not defined in BASE64_DECODE at ' var decodedInt = new DataView(new Uint8Array(atob( P ).split('').map(v => v.charCodeAt(0))).buffer).getInt16(0);' position 38 stackstrace: BASE64_DECODE line: 3```

Comment: oh, so snowflake doesn't have atob ... you'll have to write it or use [this polyfill](https://github.com/MaxArt2501/base64-js/blob/master/base64.js)

Comment: @Bravo that almost works! I executed the function with the polyfill included for the initial value given "D6A=". However, when I execute the function on a larger data set, I get the following:

[P0000][100132] JavaScript execution error: Uncaught RangeError: Offset is outside the bounds of the DataView - any ideas? Thanks so much!

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/base64_decode_string.html ? Why you need udf?

Comment: @RanLupovich that seems to work fine for encoded strings but not for encoded numbers

Comment: you probably wrote something wrong

Comment: It seems to work once I changed  ```new Uint8Array``` to ```new Uint16Array```. Thanks!

Comment: interesting - uint16array endianess may cause problems with different architectures

Comment: @Bravo you're right and I noticed that using Uint16Array produces the incorrect value as opposed to Uint8Array. I did some further digging and found the culprit to this issue. I traced the error down to a particular encoded value which is "/w==" 

I ran the Python script locally with that value an the input and it produced the correct result: 2.55

However, Javascript throws the error described previously. RangeError: Offset is outside the bounds of the DataView. I assume it doesn't like the "/"? Not sure how to handle this...

Comment: oh, right, because `/w==` is only a single byte ....

Comment: @donkey - see answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can do it using atob (polyfill as required) Uint8Array and DataView

Note, the raw `data` array is "filled" to be an even length - but the last two bytes need to be swapped, I believe

```js
var kafkaDecodeNumber = function(base64EncodedNumber) {
    var data = atob(base64EncodedNumber).split('').map(v => v.charCodeAt(0));
    if (data.length % 2) {
        data.push(0, data.pop());
    }
    var uint8 = new Uint8Array(data);
    return new DataView(uint8.buffer).getInt16(0);
}

var float = parseFloat(kafkaDecodeNumber( 'D6A=' )).toFixed(38) / 100;
console.log(float);

float = parseFloat(kafkaDecodeNumber( '/w==' )).toFixed(38) / 100;
console.log(float);
```

Actually, since the code will only ever get an encoded int16 - the code is far simpler

```js
var kafkaDecodeNumber = function(base64EncodedNumber) {
    const [a, b] = atob(base64EncodedNumber).split('').map(v => v.charCodeAt(0));
    return b === undefined ? a : a * 256 + b;
    
}

var float = parseFloat(kafkaDecodeNumber( 'D6A=' )).toFixed(38) / 100;
console.log(float);

float = parseFloat(kafkaDecodeNumber( '/w==' )).toFixed(38) / 100;
console.log(float);
```

Actually, just figured out the easiest way, given you'll only ever get a 16 bit number passed in - and this way doesn't need any base64 polyfill

```js
var kafkaDecodeNumber = function(base64EncodedNumber) {
    const b64 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
    
    const bits = base64EncodedNumber
      .replace(/=+$/g, '')
      .split('')
      .reduce((a, b) => a + b64.indexOf(b).toString(2).padStart(6, '0'), '');
      
    return parseInt(bits.match(/[01]{8}/g).join('').padStart(16, '0'), 2);
}

var float = parseFloat(kafkaDecodeNumber( 'D6A=' )).toFixed(38) / 100;
console.log(float);

float = parseFloat(kafkaDecodeNumber( '/w==' )).toFixed(38) / 100;
console.log(float);
```